# Check for column type if statement

Tags: t-sql

I want to add `int` Primary Key if column `Id` is a nvarchar. I have a vague idea how to do it:

```
DECLARE @columnType ... = SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
 TABLE_NAME = 'TempTable' AND 
 COLUMN_NAME = 'Id';
IF ISNUMERIC(@columnType)<>1
    ALTER TABLE TempTable ALTER COLUMN Id int IDENTITY(1,1), ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id);
ELSE
    ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id);
```

I don't know how to make it work but I think I'm pretty close.

Comment: `@columnType` will contain SQL Server datatypes like INT, DECIMAL, VARCHAR. So yes, pretty close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do what I wanted. Maybe someone will benefit from this:

```
IF 'Int' in (SELECT DATA_TYPE 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'TempTable' AND 
    COLUMN_NAME = 'Id')
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD Idd int IDENTITY (1,1)
        ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Idd)
    END
GO
```

Basicaly it checks if column is of type `INT` if yes, it adds Primary Key on Id column. If it isn't it creates new column `Idd` and makes it int Primary Key.

Pretty specific problem, maybe someone will make use of my torment.

EDIT: Something is wrong with checking whether `Int` is in selected type.

Comment: Please note it's best practice to always name your constraints.